# How I can establish A/B test framework?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, sample-size, ab-test

I know that my question has big scope but I would like to get your perspective especially from statistical point of view.

I want to establish A/B framework specially for our feature tests. We are taking a decision based on data. However we would like to do it in a more significant way. In our tests, we are taking account of metrics like expected profit, number or products that we sold during the test, visits. The metrics that we used also increase based on the test. Regarding to topic of the test, we can decide to go with more than 2 groups. So it means that I couldn't use 2x2 chi-square calculators directly. It seems that I may develop my calculator with supported with business perspective and sub-calculators like sample size, duration calculators and so on.

So with this in mind, I would like to discuss 3 topics:

1. How I can decide sample size of the test?
2. How I can determine the duration of test?
3. Regarding to above questions how can I check statistical significance of the test?

This is open-discussion, feel free to add your comments and suggestions!
Cheers

Comment: Questions in the SE system are supposed to be narrow & 
concrete such that they can be given a definitively 
correct, factual answer in at  most a few paragraphs. 
This isn't a site for discussions or opinions.